# Best Practice: Failed Transactional Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

What is best practice for failed transactional emails? The company has legal obligations to send receipts and other important emails, but sometimes list detective filters them out.

I am interested in finding out how people navigate this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason list detective is filtering them out? If it is because their subscriber status is 'held,' it is likely because the email has met the criteria from multiple bounces.

Obviously it is impossible to send to an email address that bounces.

What I've done at my company is used journey builder to create a salesforce case for bounced transactional emails so that our customer service team can follow up for a new email address via phone.

We've also created a daily automation that imports any contacts previously bounced who have had their email address updated via filedrop and resets the marketing cloud status on the all subscribers list.